# How to overwrite certain words in txt file

Tags: java, text, overwrite

So I'm trying to overwrite a text file that sort of looks like this:

```
FPS_CAP = 60 
RANDOM_SETTING = 1 
RANDOM_SETTING2 = 1
```

I want to be able to change the value of FPS_CAP to a different number. How do I do that?

Comment: Show your own effort and code trying to solve the problem. If you get stuck at a specific issue, you can ask here.

Answer (score 0):

I propose to use sed.

```
sed -i "s/FPS_CAP = 60/FPS_CAP = NEWVALUE/" /path/to/text/file.txt
```

If you have some more constraints or already started with an approach provide that info in the question.